# Is it fine to say in comparative degree?

Tags: comparative-degree

> D.r A.P.J Abdul Kalam was more wise and highly-educated than you think.

Is it ok to place in that sentence “highly” before “educated” to make comparative degree with compound adjective?

Answer (score 1):

Your construction is possible but could be improved.

If you want to make it clear that you intend the comparative degree to apply to both, it would be better to write:

> ....was both wiser and more highly-educated than you think.**

Comment: Syntactically,  the comparative degree (the word ***more***) ***must*** to apply to both, because of the trailing ***than-*** clause. Otherwise it would have to be *...more wise than you think, and highly-educated.* An odd thing to say, but at least it's syntactically valid.

Comment: FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica and Ronald Sole, thanks!